# Edit contents of Modal popup in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to edit the contents of a modal popup in R shiny. Below is my code with which I'm able to print the values in the modal popup but I'm not able to edit it.

```
Server.R

modelnetlist <- function(failed = FALSE){
    netlistdata <- readLines('run.scs')
    splitText1 <- stringi::stri_split(str = netlistdata, regex = '\\n')
    
    # wrap a paragraph tag around each element in the list
    replacedText1 <- lapply(splitText1, p)
    modalDialog(
      title = "Netlist File",
      replacedText1,
      easyClose = FALSE,
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Close"),
        actionButton("save", "Save")
      )
    )

  }
  
  observeEvent(input$gennet, {
    
    showModal(modelnetlist())
  })

ui.R

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "yellow",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Modelling Automation"), 
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
                        id = "tabs",
                        
                        menuItem("Data Processing", tabName = "DP", icon = icon("database"), startExpanded = TRUE,
                                 menuSubItem("Merge", tabName= "Merge"),
                                 menuSubItem("Data", tabName = "Data"),
                                 menuSubItem("Plot", tabName = "Plot", selected = TRUE),
                                 menuSubItem("Parameters", tabName = "Parameters")),
                        menuItem("Parameter Extraction", icon = icon("book-open"), tabName = "PE"),
                                  menuSubItem("Data Conversion", tabName = "DC"),
                                  menuSubItem("IPL Upload", tabName = "IPL"),
                                  menuSubItem("Netlist Spectre", tabName = "netlist"),
                                  menuSubItem("Spectre logs", tabName = "mylog"),
                                  menuSubItem("Parameter Fitting", tabName = "PF"),
                        
                        
                        menuItem("Model QA", tabName = "QA", icon = icon("angellist"))
                      ),
                      
                      textOutput("res")
                    ),
                    
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem("DP", "Dashboard tab content"),
                        #tabItem("PE", "Widgets tab content"),
                        tabItem("Merge", fileInput("mergefiles", "choose the files", accept = c(".txt"), multiple = TRUE), downloadButton("Download", label = "Merged File")),
                        tabItem("Data",
                                
                                mainPanel(div(style='overflow-x:scroll',tableOutput("txt"),tableOutput("filetable"),tableOutput("filetable1")))
                        ),
                        
                        tabItem("Plot",sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(width=3,
                                                                  fileInput("datasets", "choose the files", accept = c(".txt",".esd"), multiple = TRUE),
                                                                  uiOutput("plotdata"),uiOutput("devicetype"), uiOutput("chip"),
                                                                  uiOutput("macro"),
                                                                  uiOutput("device"),fluidRow(column(5,uiOutput("minIT2")),column(5,uiOutput("maxIT2"))),
                                                                  fluidRow(column(5,uiOutput("temperature")), column(5,uiOutput("DCleakage"))),
                                                                  fluidRow(column(5,uiOutput("varx")),column(5,uiOutput("vary")))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(width=9,
                                  plotlyOutput("PLOT")))),
                        
                        tabItem("Parameters",tags$style(type="text/css",
                                  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                 ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),
                                div(style="display:inline-block;width:32%;text-align: center;",actionButton("action", label = "Normalize")),
                                tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                                            tabPanel("CV Table",div(style='overflow-x:scroll',dataTableOutput('DiodeCVTable')),fluidRow(column(5, actionButton("perimeterCV", label="Change Perimeter")),column(5, actionButton("changeCV", label = "Change Goldenchip"))),fluidRow(column(5, uiOutput("dynamicCV")),column(5,uiOutput("goldenchipCV"))),plotlyOutput("cvplot")),
                                            tabPanel("DC Table",div(style='overflow-x:scroll',dataTableOutput('DiodeDCTable')),fluidRow(column(5, actionButton("perimeterDC", label="Change Perimeter")),column(5, actionButton("changeDC", label = "Change Goldenchip"))),fluidRow(column(5, uiOutput("dynamicDC")),column(5,uiOutput("goldenchipDC"))),plotlyOutput("dcplot")),
                                            tabPanel("TLP Table",div(style='overflow-x:scroll',dataTableOutput('TLPTable')), fluidRow(column(5, actionButton("perimeterTLP", label="Change Perimeter")),column(5, actionButton("changeTLP", label = "Change Goldenchip"))),fluidRow(column(5, uiOutput("dynamicTLP")),column(5,uiOutput("goldenchipTLP"))),plotlyOutput("tlpplot")),
                                            tabPanel("VFTLP Table",div(style='overflow-x:scroll',dataTableOutput('VFTLPTable')), fluidRow(column(5, actionButton("perimeterVFTLP", label="Change Perimeter")),column(5, actionButton("changeVFTLP", label = "Change Goldenchip"))),fluidRow(column(5, uiOutput("dynamicVFTLP")),column(5,uiOutput("goldenchipVFTLP"))), plotlyOutput("vftlpplot")))),
                        
                        tabItem("PE","Parameter Extraction Content"),
                        tabItem("DC",uiOutput("onedevice"),uiOutput('tabs'), 
                               
                                   conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='CV'", plotlyOutput("plotcv1"),br(), tableOutput("device1cv")),
                                #conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='CV 2'", plotlyOutput("plotcv2"),br(), tableOutput("device2cv")),
                               # conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='CV 3'", plotlyOutput("plotcv3"),br(), tableOutput("device2cv")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='DC @ 25'", plotlyOutput("plotdc125"),br(), tableOutput("device1dc25")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='DC @ -40'", plotlyOutput("plotdc140"),br(), tableOutput("device1dc40")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='DC @ 125'", plotlyOutput("plotdc1125"),br(), tableOutput("device1dc125")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='DC @ 150'", plotlyOutput("plotdc1150"),br(), tableOutput("device1dc150")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='TLP'",fluidRow(column(3,uiOutput("stepcountTLP")), column(3, uiOutput("maxvoltageTLP")), column(3, uiOutput("VholdTLP")), downloadButton("DownloadTLP",label = "Download converted data")), plotlyOutput("plottlp1"),br(), tableOutput("device1tlp")),
                               #conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='TLP 2'", plotlyOutput("plottlp2"),br(), tableOutput("device2tlp")),
                               
                                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.layer=='VFTLP'",fluidRow(column(3,uiOutput("stepcountVFTLP")), column(3, uiOutput("maxvoltageVFTLP")), column(3, uiOutput("VholdVFTLP"))), plotlyOutput("plotvftlp1"),br(), tableOutput("device1vftlp"))
                                
                                ),
                        tabItem("PF",  uiOutput('modelingtabs'),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.modtab=='CV'",tableOutput("modelingdevice1CV")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition= "input.modtab=='DC @ 25'", tableOutput("modelingdevice1DC25")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition= "input.modtab=='DC @ 40'", tableOutput("modelingdevice1DC40")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition= "input.modtab=='DC @ 125'", tableOutput("modelingdevice1DC125")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition= "input.modtab=='DC @ 150'", tableOutput("modelingdevice1DC150")),# plotlyOutput("plotcv1"),br(), tableOutput("device1cv")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.modtab=='TLP'",tableOutput("modelingdevice1TLP")),# plotlyOutput("plottlp1"),br(), tableOutput("device1tlp")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition="input.modtab=='VFTLP'",tableOutput("modelingdevice1VFTLP"))#, plotlyOutput("plotvftlp1"),br(), tableOutput("device1vftlp"))
                        ),
                        tabItem("IPL", 
                                fluidRow(box(title = "Model Inputs", width = 8,
                                         fileInput("iplfile", "choose the IPL file", accept = c(".xlsx"), multiple = TRUE),
                                         column(3, uiOutput("modeltype")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("modeldevtype")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("modelpath")), 
                                         column(3, uiOutput("wrapperfile")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("zapcon")), 
                                         column(3,uiOutput("polarity")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("sectiontype")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("designfile")), 
                                         column(3, uiOutput("esd_event")),
                                         column(3, uiOutput("esd_exit")),
                                         column(3, uiOutput("modelnodeorder")),
                                         column(3, uiOutput("terminalbias")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("design")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("modtemp")),
                                         column(3,uiOutput("ylogaxis")))), 
                                         box(title = "Model Parameters in IPL", width = 20, tableOutput("IPLTable"),
                                             uiOutput("newvalue1"),
                                             uiOutput("newvalue2"),
                                             uiOutput("newvalue3"),
                                             uiOutput("newvalue4"))
                                ,fluidRow(box(width = 6, height = 60,actionButton("SpecPlot", label="Spectre Plot", width = 100),
                                              # bsModal("netl", strong("Netlist File", style="color:#0000ff; font-size:120%"), 
                                              #         "gennet", size = "large", uiOutput("modelnetlist")),
                                          actionButton("HspiPlot", label="Hspice Plot", width = 100),
                                          actionButton("gennet", label="Generate netlist"),
                                          actionButton("ChangeValues", label="Change Values"),
                                          actionButton("save", label = "Save"),
                                          actionButton("Mergesim", label="Merge Simulation Plots"))),
                                          uiOutput("newvalues"),  
                                          #conditionalPanel(condition = "input$specplot", withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plotspe"), type = 1, hide.ui = FALSE)),
                                          tags$head(
                                          tags$style(
                                          HTML(".shiny-notification {
                                          height: 100px;
                                          width: 500px;
                                          position:fixed;
                                          top: calc(50% - 50px);;
                                          left: calc(50% - 400px);;
                                          }
                                          "
                                          )
                                            )
                                              ),
                                          #box(title = "Simulation", status = "primary", plotlyOutput("plotspe", height = 250)),
                                          fluidRow(column(width=6,
                                                          fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plotspe",width = "100%", height = "400px", inline = FALSE))),
                                                          
                                                   column(width=6,
                                                          fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plothspi",width = "100%", height = "400px", inline = FALSE)))),
                                          fluidRow(column(width=6,fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plotspechspi",width = "100%", height = "400px", inline = FALSE)))),
                                          # splitLayout(style = "height:400px;", cellWidths = c("800", "800"),
                                          #             plotlyOutput("plotspe"), plotlyOutput("plothspi"))
                                          # ,
                                          plotlyOutput("plottlpalongspectre")
                                          ),
                        tabItem("netlist", fluidPage(uiOutput("netlistfile"))),
                        tabItem("mylog", fluidPage(uiOutput("logfile"))),
                        
                        tabItem("QA", " QA tab content")# actionButton("ChangeValues", label="Change Values"
                      )
                    )
)

**run.scs file:** (File that I'm calling in modelnetlist function to read and display it in the modal)

Simmulator lang=spectre
global 0
paropt options redefinedparams= ignore 
parameters vnw=0 vnd=0 
parameters area_1=5.5e-12
```

I would like to edit in the modal popup, but I'm only to print with my code. I tried textInput, textOutput inside modalDialog but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible?

Comment: Do you want me to add ui code? Already attached my server logic and the file in which I'm reading and displaying

Comment: At least you must put an input such as `textAreaInput` in order to "enter" modifications . Your first try as you stated is purely static (display). Have you tried to do this ?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to have this as a running application so that we can test our answer and make sure that it actually works as expected. If you are `ui` code is not too lengthy you can add it here.

Comment: @RonakShah I have added my ui.R file as well. Apologies, it is too big. But I think now you will be reproduce. Look for the button Generate netlist in the IPL upload tab.

Comment: @Billy34 How do I use textAreaInput inside modelDialog? modalDialog(
      title = "Netlist File",
      replacedText1,). How do I replace the static value(replacedText1) into a textAreaInput as you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `modalDialog` function you can use almost any UI elements (see `...` parameter)

```
modelnetlist <- function(failed = FALSE){
  netlistdata <- paste(readLines('run.scs'),collapse="\n")
  modalDialog(
    title = "Netlist File",
    textAreaInput("theScript", value=netlistdata),
    easyClose = FALSE,
    footer = tagList(
      modalButton("Close"),
      actionButton("save", "Save")
    )
  )
}
```

and to get new script in the save button listener use `input$theScript`

```
observeEvent(input$save, {
  # do whatever you want with input$theScript
  if(isTruthy(input$theScript))
    writeLines(input$theScript, "run.scs")
})
```

Note: the path where you save file must be writeable.

Comment: Getting this error, "Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector"

Comment: It works with the below code, "textAreaInput("thescript", "Netlist",value=replacedText1, width = "750px", height = "1000px")". But the text is being displayed with an additional, <p>   "<p>simulator lang=spectre</p>". How to remove <p>?

Comment: it expects a single string and not a vector of strings as readLines returns. so need to concatenate them using new lines (updated my answer). No need to replace/add p. straight from the file (except inserting newlines during paste)

Comment: Could you help on how to save the textinput contents as run.scs file? I tried to use input$theScript but I'm not able to save it

Comment: I amended the code to save the content in a file